# Need to be able to switch directory and execute shell script in remote server in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

The requirement is to login to a remote server using some credentials, then switch to another user and path and execute a shell script. Though I have found a way to login to remote server but unable to figure out the other steps. Any insight would be highly helpful. The following block of code does the login but then fails to switch user and change directory.

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'QA'
remote.host = '193.401.200.001'
remote.user =  'admin'
remote.password = 'admin'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    
stage('Remote SSH') {
   sshCommand remote: remote, sh "pbrun su - myuser"
   sshCommand remote: remote, sh "cd /apps"
   sshScript remote: remote, script: "demo.sh"
}
```

Comment: Consider using Ansible (either through manual server installation or a Docker container) to access the target machine and do whatever operations you want to do. It is always possible to do it through Groovy/Shell commands with SSH, but I would say Ansible is way more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll put my thoughts as an answer.

If you need to run things as a different user you should just SSH in using that user (in your case the `myuser` user)

Also each `sshCommand` will run inside the users home directory, so running the `cd` will put you into that directory just for that execution and not for the subsequent call to `demo.sh`.

I believe the below would accomplish what you are after:

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'QA'
remote.host = '193.401.200.001'
remote.user =  'myuser'
remote.password = 'myuser-password'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                
stage('Remote SSH') {
   sshCommand remote: remote, sh "/apps/demo.sh"
}
```